# How can I send a String value to any particular app from another app without using ContentProvider or sharedPreference

Tags: java, android

appA mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnSendBroadcast;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnSendBroadcast = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendBroadcast);
        btnSendBroadcast.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.admin.chromium");
        intent.putExtra("KeyName","code1id");
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        intent.setComponent(
                new ComponentName("com.example.admin.chromiumsendmessage","com.example.admin.chromiumsendmessage.MainActivity"));
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "KeyName value sent to ChromiumSendMessage app" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

appB manifest--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.admin.chromiumsendmessage">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcast"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.admin.chromium" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

appB receiver class:

```
public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String msg;
    String name;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


   msg = intent.getStringExtra("KeyName");

   name= msg;

        Toast.makeText(context, "value  - " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }
}
```

[AppB manifest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pd6J.png) [appA mainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43yz1.png)

There are two Applications, appA & appB. In appA there is a button. In appA, if I click on the button it should send some value (`String/Integer`) to the appB without the use of `ContentProvider` or `SharedPreference`. Moreover, the appB should receiver the value in its' `BroadcastReceiver` class. Could anyone help me please?

I have added appA MainActivity code and Receiver class and Manifest from appB.

Comment: Make use of Bluetoot API.

Comment: Call `sendBroadcast()` in App A. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html).

Comment: if i am using Bluetooth Api then i should keep both the appA and appB in separate device but what i want is -- both the appA and appB will be on same device and can send data from appA to appB's receiver class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sendBroadcast()` method to send `String` value from one app to another.

However, first of all you need to register your receiver app in `Manifest`.

For instance, suppose you have two apps, **App1** and **App2**.

**App1** will send the String value and **App2** will receive that value.

In your **App1**, code should be like this,

```
final Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.pkg.App1");
intent.putExtra("KeyName","code1id");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setComponent(  
    new ComponentName("com.pkg.App2","com.pkg.App2.MyBroadcastReceiver"));  
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

To receive this broadcast message in **App2**, write code in `Manifest` of your **App2** following below:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.pkg.App1" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES flag is added to the intent before it is
>   sent to indicate that the intent is to be allowed to start a component
>   of a stopped application.

Comment: Hi Mahedi , i have done exactly how you said but the appB couldn't get the value i pass from appA,

Comment: i have added all my coding above , please suggest where i am lagging ...Thank you

Comment: I have added my coding here for your better understanding , please guide me where i going wrong .. Thank You.

Comment: well, change in your appA to intent.setComponent(
                new ComponentName("com.example.admin.chromiumsendmessage","com.example.admin.chromiumsendmessage.MyBroadcast"));

Comment: Hi , Thanks much,  it worked after i put intent.setpackage(com.pkg.App2)  and in the aap2 manifest <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.pkg.App2" />
    </intent-filter>

Comment: You're welcome, if you find this answer is useful, don't forget to accept this answer by marking tick(✓) on the top-left of this answer to help others.

Comment: M a new comer though , i marked. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice job. welcome anyway.